# TYPO3 new version

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-10.x

I'm preparing myself to work with the new version of TYPO3 (v10), and I need clear documentation which presents the changes between the old and new version (especially disappear of ("switchableControllerActions")

So if anyone has an idea I'll be grateful

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `switchableControllerActions` didn't disappear. You can see all changes in the release notes, e.g. https://get.typo3.org/release-notes/10.4.6

Comment: I'm sorry about downvoting and closing this question. I'm really sorry because I can't downvote it even more. These things are specified in docs as Bernd showed you, and you really should start with reading docs instead asking useless questions.

Answer (score 1):

There always (for all major versions) are slides "What's new" and a search gives this page: https://typo3.org/help/documentation/whats-new

the other option is the change log / Release Notes for each bugfix version:
https://get.typo3.org/list/version/10

And all together in one page: https://docs.typo3.org/Home/WhatsNew.html

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the answer given, I would recommend the [Changelogs](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog-10.html) in any case. The "What's new Slides" do not contain all changes. The changelogs contain all relevant changes as each change in the core with a deprecation or breaking change must include a Changelog. Also, the Changelogs contain a migration path and tips that should be helpful for you.

I admit, it is a huge long list. So here are some additional tips:

- Since you mention switchableControllerActions: For your own extensions, you can use the [extension scanner](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/10.4/en-us/ApiOverview/ExtensionScanner/Index.html) to search for deprecated or breaking functionality in your extension before moving to the next version: In the backend: *Upgrade > Scan Extension Files*
- Also, since TYPO3 9, you can view and check off the changelogs you already handled in the backend, see *Upgrade > View Upgrade Documentation* in the Backend.

[image]

If you want to find out about changes even earlier, you can follow the changes via one of these sources and read them as soon as they come out:

- https://typo3.slack.com: channel #rst-updates
- https://review.typo3.org and read the core patches and follow the discussions
- twitter: https://twitter.com/t3git_master

What I am also sometimes missing is a table with comparison of old and new. But there are some good resources for specific things, such as:

- migrating to "new" doctrine QueryBuilder from [$GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/10.4/en-us/ApiOverview/Database/Migration/Index.html)

About the what / when / why of some particular changes: The changelog explains it quite well, including a migration path. What is sometimes missing is, why a change was made. There is also often some more information and discussions in the review on Gerrit. To find that, click on the link to the issue in the changelog and then find the link to the review (should start with https://review.typo3.org) in the history.